# Use value in one component and reset in another

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a simple ReactJS component, that makes use of some state, `myValue`, which is stored in a context.

On this page I render `myValue` in some HTML, and also in a button.

I want the original value of `myValue` to be rendered in the HTML, but I want to set the value in the context to be 0.

The button should always display the value held in the context, which should be rendered as 0 on the page.

```js
export function MyComponent() {
    const { myValue, setMyValue } = useContext(myValueContext);

    useClearData(); // Should be called somewhere to reset myValue to 0

    return (
        <React.Fragment>
            <MyValueButton /> {/* Should display myValue as 0 */}
            <main className="App">
                <div>
                    My value is the original {myValue} which should be non-zero!
                </div>
            </main>
        </React.Fragment>
    );
}
```

How do I structure this code so that the button re-renders when the context changes, but the HTML does not?

Answer (score 0):

So, to answer my own question, this needs the [useRef](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#useref) hook:

```js
export function MyComponent() {
    const { myValue, setMyValue } = useContext(myValueContext);
    myValueRef = useRef(myvalue);
    useClearData(); // Should be called somewhere to reset myValue to 0

    return (
        <React.Fragment>
            <MyValueButton /> {/* Should display myValue as 0 */}
            <main className="App">
                <div>
                    My value is the original {myValueRef.current.toString()} which should be non-zero!
                </div>
            </main>
        </React.Fragment>
    );
}
```